# How to retrieve difficulty via api

Tags: exchange-api

Im trying to retrieve the current difficulty value via api and parse the value only using JQ. In this example it is etherchains api. Currently my output is

```
curl 'https://etherchain.org/api/difficulty' | jq '.data'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    52  100    52    0     0    129      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   129
[
  {
    "difficulty": 666836759051894
  }
]
```

and I would like it to be

```
666836759051894
```

When I look at the jq manual https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters it shows

```
    jq '.foo'
Input   {"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"}
Output  42
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `curl` into silent mode first...

```
$ curl -s 'https://etherchain.org/api/difficulty' | jq '.data[][]'
666201861413999
```

Comment: what are the square brackets at the end doing?